# How to grab video frame in a numpy array using vlc python bindings?

Tags: python, numpy, vlc, libvlc

I want grab each video frames from libvlc in a (2D) numpy array using python.
I expect to use vlc.MediaPlayer.video_set_callbacks(...)
with [callbacks][1] managing an numpy array but there is no  documentation about using callback **with python**.

Any Idea or alternative ways ?

[1]: decorated with vlc.cb.VideoLockCb and its friends

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at [PyFFmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) ? I do not use this python module, thus I don't know how well it works but it does adevertize the feature you require.

**Edit**

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is also worth a try. It is probably more stable.
OpenCV offers no less than two python bindings. The later, better one being cv2 is integrated with numpy. It is much easier to use than the older cv module. As an example, you can read video frames with the following code:

```
import cv2
filename = 'myfile.mpg'
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
retval, im = capture.read()
```

Each call to `.read` will output a new frame of the video.

Comment: pyffmpeg version 2.0/ 2.1 /2.2 apha do not compile under ubuntu 11.04 and 12.04 (my OS)

Comment: I need vlc because my video could come form any source : network streaming, firewire, filesystem ...

Comment: @VincentAgnus hi, have you solved the problem? If yes, can you share the solution for me, thank you.